# Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'AppCtrl' is not registered

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $mdDialog, ) {


    $scope.showAdvanced = function (ev) {
        $mdDialog.show({
            controller: DialogController,
            templateUrl: 'dialog1.tmpl.html',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            targetEvent: ev,
            clickOutsideToClose: true
        })

    };

    function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
        $scope.hide = function () {
            $mdDialog.hide();
        };

        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $mdDialog.cancel();
        };

        $scope.answer = function (answer) {
            $mdDialog.hide(answer);
        };
    }
});
```

**it come out an error**
anyone can help to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to register your `DialogController` in order to use it and provide it's named reference as `string` to AppCtrl.

your code should be like:

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
   .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $mdDialog) {
      $scope.showAdvanced = function (ev) {
          $mdDialog.show({
            controller: 'DialogController', // notice single qoutes here
            templateUrl: 'dialog1.tmpl.html',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            targetEvent: ev,
            clickOutsideToClose: true
        })    
     }) // end of 'AppCtrl'
   .controller('DialogController', function ($scope, $mdDialog) {
        $scope.hide = function () {
            $mdDialog.hide();
        };

        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $mdDialog.cancel();
        };

        $scope.answer = function (answer) {
            $mdDialog.hide(answer);
        };
    }); // end of 'DialogController'
```

Comment: .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $mdDialog, ) {.....you need to remove last ,(Comma) after  $mdDialog.This will also give syntax error